# Set post params with volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to send a POST request with volley but I am not sure how to set the params. I tried this code

```
Map<String,String> map  = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("test", "test");
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, String.valueOf(new JSONArray(map)), this, this);
```

The app crashes when this code is executed with the error

> Activity com.example.test.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add POST parameters to your request you need to override the `getParams()` and 2 other methods of `Request` class:

```
public class MapJARequest extends Request<JSONArray> {

  private final Map<String, String> params;

  private Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener;

  public MapJARequest( int method, String url, Map<String,String> params, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener ) {
    super( method, url, errorListener );
    this.params = params;
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    return params;
  }

  @Override
  protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse( NetworkResponse response ) {
    try{
      String jsonString = new String( response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset( response.headers ) );
      return Response.success( new JSONArray( jsonString ), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders( response ) );
    }catch( Exception je ){
      return Response.error( new ParseError( je ) );
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void deliverResponse( JSONArray response ) {
    listener.onResponse( response );
  }

}
```

Be aware that you can not inherit from `JsonArrayRequest` straight away unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

you are **down casting jsonArray to a string** try not doing it.

This should help you,

`JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONArray(map), this, this);`

Let me know if u are still facing this issue.

Comment: Thanks but I got this error org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class java.util.HashMap